# $(AB)^p =A^p B^p$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, functional-calculus

Let $A,B$ be two positive bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space. If $A$ commutes with $B$, do we have $(AB)^p =A^p B^p$ for any $p>0$? Or more general, $f(AB) = f(A)f(B)$ for any Borel function $f$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes for powers, but not for general $f$.  For example, it's hardly ever true for $f(x) = 2x$.  It's true for powers because $(xy)^p = x^p y^p$ for $x,y \in [0, \infty)$; apply the Gelfand isomorphism on $C(\Delta)$ where $\Delta$ is the maximal ideal space of the commutative C* algebra generated by $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Really great answer ! Thx